# Why does byte not get type promoted to long (Type promotion during method overloading)

Tags: java, overloading, type-promotion

In the first piece of code byte gets type promoted to integer type

```
public class Main
{
    Main(int a,byte b){
        System.out.println("int 1");
    }
    
    Main(int a,float b){
        System.out.println("float 1");
    }
    
    Main(float a,int b){
        System.out.println("float 2");
    }
    
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        byte a = 10;
        byte b = 20;
        Main obj = new Main(a,b);
    }
}
```

***Output***
int 1

In the second code the compiler throws an error

```
public class Main
{
    Main(long a,byte b){
        System.out.println("int 1");
    }
    
    Main(int a,float b){
        System.out.println("float 1");
    }
    
    Main(float a,int b){
        System.out.println("float 2");
    }
    
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        byte a = 10;
        byte b = 20;
        Main obj = new Main(a,b);
    }
}
```

***Error***

```
Main.java:25: error: reference to Main is ambiguous
        Main obj = new Main(a,b);
                   ^
  both constructor Main(int,float) in Main and constructor Main(float,int) in Main match
1 error


** Process exited - Return Code: 1 **
```

Why in the second code the constructor with long a and byte b as parameters is not being called?

Comment: What is your reason for thinking it should be?

Comment: If you added `Main(byte a,int b){
        System.out.println("int 1a");
    }`  to your first example you would have the same problem.  There is not exact match and there are more than one equally weighted constructors

Comment: ... Because that's how the standard says it works? What kind of answer are you looking for exactly?

Comment: Why wasn't there an ambiguity error in the first code. I'm sorry if i'm not making any sense

Comment: There was no ambiguity, because the Java Language Specification (JLS) specifies exactly how this should be resolved.